# What command in monitrc can I use to start/stop systemd services?

Tags: linux, systemd, monit

I like using monit for the web interface where I can see running monitored processes. I recently upgraded a server to Ubuntu 16.04 and it is using systemd.

I have everything else running but I cannot find the right monit commands to control systemd...

I used to do `/etc/init.d/process start` or `stop` or whatever. That obivously no longer works so I tried ...

`systemctl start process` which didn't work either. What can I do here? My monitrc is pasted below...(old style which worked on 14.04)

```
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"

check process sshd with pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
    start program = "etc/init.d/ssh start"
    stop program = "etc/init.d/ssh stop"
```

Answer (score 15):

This should work on RHEL / CentOS 7 / Ubuntu 18.04

```
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
    start program = "/bin/systemctl start nginx"
    stop program = "/bin/systemctl stop nginx"

check process sshd with pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
    start program = "/bin/systemctl start sshd"
    stop program = "/bin/systemctl stop sshd"
```

Answer (score 4):

Monit expects all paths to be fully qualified. It is clearly the Monit Control File (/etc/monit/monitrc).

In this case fully qualified path for `systemctl` is required to be specified.

On `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`, I used `which systemctl` to find its fully qualified path which was `/usr/sbin/systemctl`.

So, below given snippet worked for me.

```
start program = "/usr/sbin/systemctl start nginx"
stop program = "/usr/sbin/systemctl stop nginx"
```

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu 16 or later, you can using systemctl then start or stop services:

```
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
    start program = "systemctl start nginx"
    stop program = "systemctl stop nginx"

check process sshd with pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
    start program = "systemctl start sshd"
    stop program = "systemctl stop sshd"
```

Comment: that does not work, I get an alert that says "Description: failed to start (exit status -1) -- Program systemctl failed: File 'systemctl' does not exist"

Comment: and if I use absolute paths I get alerts that stop action was done, but in my ssh session it says it is still running and my syslog says it did nothing

Comment: @deltaskelta You need to give the full path, `/bin/systemctl`